# Asyncronously mapping over a collection with a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to learn how to use Bluebird promises and I am a bit lost.

I have two database tables: `topic` and `subject`.

The `topic` table has a `subject_id` column, which can then be used to query the `subject` table for the subject title.

I have an `orm` that queries asynchronously and returns a promise.

Ultimately I am trying to write a model method for topics that does the lookup for you, injecting the `subject_title` returned from the subsequent `subject` queries into the each element in the array of objects initially returned from the `topic` query.

I am trying to use `Promise.map`, but this is not working. The code below does not work. I never expected it to, but I think it captures the essence of what i am trying to accomplish.

```
var promise = orm.select({
    db:     db, 
    table:  'topic',  
    where:  args.where,
    order:  args.order,
    limit:  args.limit,
    offset: args.offset,
    group:  args.group
}).map(function (topic) {
    var promise = orm.select({
        db: db,
        table: 'subject',
        qrm: 'one',
        where: {id: topic.subject_id}
    }).then(function (subject) {
        topic.subject_title = subject;
    });
    return promise;
});

return promise;
```

So, assuming that a vanilla `topic` object has the properties:

```
[subject_id, title, description]
```

And a `subject` object has:

```
[id, title]
```

I want the above function to return an array of objects with the following properties:

```
[subject_id, subject_title, title, description]
```

What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not avoid mutation and return a new object with your new property?

Comment: What does `orm.select()` return?  Is it returning a bluebird promise?  And, what is the fulfilled data?

Comment: @jfriend00 It returns a bluebird promise. The fufilled data is an array of objects. Each object in the array represents a row in the `topics` table.

Comment: @elclanrs I have no reason to prefer mutation over returning a new array. Whatever is easiest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you just need to return the modified `topic` object from your `.then()` handler so it stays the fulfilled value:

```
return orm.select({
    db:     db, 
    table:  'topic',  
    where:  args.where,
    order:  args.order,
    limit:  args.limit,
    offset: args.offset,
    group:  args.group
}).map(function (topic) {
    return orm.select({
        db: db,
        table: 'subject',
        qrm: 'one',
        where: {id: topic.subject_id}
    }).then(function (subject) {
        topic.subject_title = subject;
        // Add return here so topic stays the fulfilled value
        return topic;
    });
});
```

The fullfilled value of the top level promise should be an array of modified topic objects.

Comment: oh! You're right, that works. I was under the assumption that I would end up with an array of promises instead of an array of results. How does the `map` function know to wait for all of the promises to be fulfilled until fulfilling it self?

Comment: @LukeP - That's what `.map()` on a Bluebird promise does.  It's just a shortcut for collecting an array of promises by iterating an array and then calling `Promise.all()` which obviously waits for all the promises you pass it before resolving it's master promise.  The [bluebird doc for `.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) explains it pretty well.